Dynamic Facebook preview image
In my app at seaofpo.vispo.com, I have a static Facebook preview image via a meta tag in the head of property="og:image". But, typically, the URL is dynamic, such as https://seaofpo.vispo.com?p=ja or https://seaofpo.vispo.com?p=mp , which displays something different. I would like to be able to post on Facebook URLs such as the latter ones, and have the preview image draw from what appears on the screen in those cases.

just change your og:image depending on the get parameter then, with your server language....?

There is no server-side computing in this project. If possible, I'd want the image generated on the fly, client-side. Impossible?

yes, facebook ignores javascript, so all relevant metatags have to be in the original source already. prerender.io might help, for example.
